# Have Edit text be copied to a textView with a button in a different layout

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am trying to get a user input from a Edit text to be copied to a next activity in my app with a button. Basically, when someone types into the Edit text, they press a submit button and the text that they typed will print in Activity2. I saw the thread that has the answer, but I don't understand it.  If someone can help me on how to do this, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Basically, I want when someone types in the Edit text, for it to be displayed on the next activity with a press of a button.